# Checkbox inside Checkbox in a dropdownlist box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was working on creating checkbox inside checkbox which all should appear inside a dropdownlist box.  I was succeeded in creating a couple of checkboxes inside a dropdownlist box.  follow the link http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/metroplots/drp/drpcheck.php

Now i am trying to create a checkbox which should appear once user clicks one checkbox.  For instance if user checks documents then a couple of checkbox should appear below that checkbox.

```
Eg.  []Documents  (if user checks main,  the sub checkboxes should appear)
           []Doc 1 
           []Doc 2
           []Doc 3
     []Phots (if user checks) 
           []photo 1
           []photo 2
           []photo 3
```

How to attain this through javascript or jquery.

Thanks in Advance. !!

Comment: How does data come to your app? In a tree format?

Comment: Cannot understand your question.  Please explain clear.

Comment: Alright, do you render the list dynamically from some object with data, or does your list already exist as HTML on the page?

Comment: It exists as html on page.  i am not pulling data from any db.

Comment: May be you'll find answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867795/best-jquery-multiselect-plugin).

Comment: It doesnt look like that option exist for that plug yet. You would have to edit it in yourself. I dont even see a callback for when the list is created, however, you could insert one.

Comment: once a box is checked i can place a <div> adjacent to the box and make it work.  But i dont want to do so.  it should appear below once the main check is clicked.  Yet i have no idea how to populate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. This is what I have done:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.team').on('click',function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $(this).next().next().show();
                    }else{
                        $(this).next().next().hide();
                    }
                });
            });


        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form name="FootballClubs">

            <input type="checkbox" class="team" value="RealMadrid"/>Real Madrid<br />
            <div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;display:none;">     
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="CR"/>Cristiano Ronaldo<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SA"/>Shabi Alanso<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="IC"/>Iker Casillias<br />
            </div>  
            <input type="checkbox" class="team" value="ManCity"/>Man City<br /> 
            <div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;display:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SA"/>Sergio Aguero<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SM"/>Super Mario<br />
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is fully working example. Also, you can unchecked the checked elements, when they are hidden again.

Comment: Hello gotqn,  this model is working well.  The thing is i am already using a class where i need to bring all those into a dropdownlist box. So how to keep all those check boxex inside a dropdown?

Comment: I am working on separate idea to populate checkboxes inside dropdown.  This makes me confusion. just view the below link. you will get idea
http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/metroplots/drp/drpcheck.php

Comment: One element can have many classes. About "I am working on separate idea to populate checkboxes inside dropdown" - do you want to put the check boxes in select?

Comment: Let me try some time.. If i cant i will raise question.

Comment: please see this gotqn ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100122/populating-many-checkboxes-in-tree-structure-inside-dropdown

Comment: gotqn: Please reply my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100122/populating-many-checkboxes-in-tree-structure-inside-dropdown