# Populating Many checkboxes in tree structure inside Dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, populate

Guys Here is the checkboxes, where it displays in tree structure.  I need it to be displayed inside the dropdown.

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.team').on('click',function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $(this).next().next().show();
                    }else{
                        $(this).next().next().hide();
                    }
                });
            });


        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form name="FootballClubs">

            <input type="checkbox" class="team" value="RealMadrid"/>Real Madrid<br />
            <div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;display:none;">     
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="CR"/>Cristiano Ronaldo<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SA"/>Shabi Alanso<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="IC"/>Iker Casillias<br />
            </div>  
            <input type="checkbox" class="team" value="ManCity"/>Man City<br /> 
            <div style="padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;display:none;">
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SA"/>Sergio Aguero<br />
                <input type="checkbox" class="player" value="SM"/>Super Mario<br />
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

I am trying to populate inside a dropdown.  Help me.

Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: Could you add a sample of what you want as a result?

Comment: Just Visit this link, http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/metroplots/drp/drpcheck1.php

If first checkbox is checked couple of checkbox should appear below the Main checkbox.  Are you clear??

Comment: And all those should be inside a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jquery [UI widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) and [jSTree](http://www.jstree.com/)

Comment: Just run the above code.  I need the same output inside a dropdown.  Thankyou for your suggestions. It doesn't solve my requirement.