# php checkboxes inside

Tags: php

Hey guys i need some check boxes inside a dropdownlist which allow to select multiple check boxes and then save it to database.

I dont know how and where to start.
any one please help me ???

```
                <optgroup label="Rooms">
                    <option value="option_1"> 1</option>
                    <option value="option_2"> 2</option>
                    <option value="option_3"> 3</option>
                    <option value="option_4"> 4</option>
                    <option value="option_5"> 5</option>
                    <option value="option_6"> Modren</option>
                    <option value="option_7">Semi Modren</option>

                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

Comment: This may get handy....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097673/checkbox-inside-checkbox-in-a-dropdownlist-box

Comment: use multi-select instead http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777265/how-to-add-checkboxes-into-dropdown-in-php                                                  check this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can do this by using jquery plugin.

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: i think in below answer w00 has given you example of this plugin you just need to include the js files.

Comment: download the zip file from here and see the demos you will idea how to implement https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're using a Javascript library like jQuery or something similar. That way you can easily use a lib that converts a standard HTML multiselect to a dropdown with selectboxes, like in this example:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

From there on you can do a form submission like you would normally do. For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="somefile.php">
    <select id="example" name="example[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    $("#example").multiselect();
</script>
```

(please note the `name` is `example[]` and NOT just `example`)

Then in PHP you can iterate through the selected checkboxes like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
    foreach ( $_POST['example'] as $index => $value )
    {
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @TariqHashemee No this will not create any problems. You have access to the selected values in the `foreach` loop. It depends on how your database is designed, how you want to store to selected values and what kind of lib. you're using (ie. mysqli or PDO). So its hard to give a direct example on how to do this, since you only know how your DB is designed and what you're using. But in anyway you can easily store the data in your database.